# Mongoose populate in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to play with populate but without success ...
It's possible to do this?

I have 2 shema :
- User

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,

  products: [{
    productId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    dateAdd: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }]
}, { timestamps: true })

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default User
```

And Product :

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

const productSchema = new Schema({
  domain: String,
  originUrl: { type: String },
  price: Number,
  img: String,
  userFollow: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

export default Product
```

So I want to retrieve all the info for each of my **prodcutId**

I try this way (and many others without success):

```
User.findOne({ _id: userId }).populate({
      path: 'products.productId',
      populate: { path: 'products.productId', model: 'Products' }
}).exec(function (err, products) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('errors :' + err)
  }
  console.log('Product => ' + util.inspect(products))
})
```

Populate has no effect, same result with just the findOne()

Comment: You are not getting back `products` but one `user` with an array of `products`. And try removing `model: 'Products'` or doing `model: 'Product'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `User.findOne({ _id: userId }).populate('products.productId')` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function of MongoDB and $[lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

```
Users.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":
            {
                _id: user.id
            }
    },
    {
        "$lookup":
            {
                from: "Product",
                localField: "products",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "products"
            }
    }

])
.exec()
.then((result) => {
    //your result

})
.catch((err) => {
    // if any error
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `localField: "products.productId"`.